# NetworkX place nodes based on value

Tags: matplotlib, tree, networkx

I am new to networkX and I am trying to find a way so I can position nodes based on a value that represents a value on Y axis without changing the random X value of the nodes that make the tree look good

Using these nodes:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(430, value = 1)
G.add_node(230, value = -1)
G.add_node(220, value = 0)
G.add_node(210, value = -1)
G.add_node(10, value = 1)
G.add_edge(430,220)
G.add_edge(10,220)
G.add_edge(210,220)
G.add_edge(230,220)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

The result should be an "X" with all of 5 nodes to be on these specific 3 y-values everytime I run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this idea will work out for you, but you should be able to achieve this by:

- calling the layout-algorithm manually
- modify the positions
- plot with modified positions

Here is an example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(430, value = 1)
G.add_node(230, value = -1)
G.add_node(220, value = 0)
G.add_node(210, value = -1)
G.add_node(10, value = 1)
G.add_edge(430,220)
G.add_edge(10,220)
G.add_edge(210,220)
G.add_edge(230,220)

pos=nx.spring_layout(G)  # default layout like in your code

other_y = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'value')
for node, node_pos in pos.items():
    if node in other_y.keys():
        pos_ = pos[node]
        pos_[1] = other_y[node]
        pos[node] = pos_

f, arr = plt.subplots(2)
nx.draw_networkx(G, ax=arr[0])
arr[0].set_title('default layout')

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, ax=arr[1])
arr[1].set_title('partially y-modified')

plt.show()
```

Output (warning: might be tuned for python 3):

[image]